# Python File Running on a Remote Server

Tags: python

We have a py file on a remote server, on that remote server we have our ERP system also.  On our local machines we have a remote app (shortcut on local machine) created to access the ERP and the File Explorer on the remote server, to avoid "logging in" each time.  Is it possible to create a remote app for the py file?  We have python installed on the remote server and on the local machines.

Comment: Likely through SSH you could log into the remote server and execute the python file directly. Your "remote app" could just be a wrapper for that ssh command.

Comment: perhaps `tmux` might help here.

Comment: I think a lot more details is needed if you want a meaningful answer.